# Irrotational implies conservative without using the path-connection

Tags: general-topology, analysis, vectors, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

Let's consider a simply-connected domain $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and a smooth vector field $\mathbf{F}$ in $V$ (please don't answer considering other scenarios). Under this assumption, let's consider the following three statements

1. "$\mathbf{F}$ is conservative in $V$" (there exists a smooth scalar field $f$ in $V$ such that $\mathbf{F}=\nabla f$ everywhere)
2. "$\mathbf{F}$ is path-independent" (any line integral of $\mathbf{F}$ in $V$ depends on the extremes only)
3. "$\mathbf{F}$ is irrotational in $V$" ($\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=0$ in $V$)

It's known that:

- 1. is equivalent to 2.
- 2. is equivalent to 3.
- 1. (trivially) implies 3.

Usually, the statement 3. implies 1. is proved "climbing backwards": 3. implies 2. and 2. implies 1.

I was wondering if there exists any proof of 3. implies 1. without using the path independence. In a complete similar fashion I was wondering the same for divergence free vector fields, if they can be expressed in terms of the curl of another vector field.

Comment: You have to use simple-connectivity somehow in the proof. Of course, once you know algebraic topology, you learn that simple-connectivity  is an overkill and the weaker requirement $H_1(V, {\mathbb R})=0$ suffices, but this is a much more advanced result. Thus, I suggest, you stick to the standard proof.

Comment: In order to prove (1), you have to demonstrate the existence of $f$. The most straight-forward way of doing so is to construct it. And the most straight-forward way of doing that is by paths, which brings you to the path independence proof. Both of those "straight-forwards" are significantly easier to follow than the alternatives, which are generally to consider function spaces and show they have certain topological properties, which then imply the existence of the function you want.